One counterexample of $f\sim g\nRightarrow 3^f=\Theta(3^g)$
At first glance, $$f\sim g\Rightarrow \lim_{x\to \infty}f/g=1\Rightarrow \lim_{x\to \infty}c^f/c^g=1,c\text{ is one constant}\Rightarrow c^f\sim c^g\Rightarrow c^f=\Theta(c^g).$$ But my textbook says there is one counterexample at least for $c=3$, could someone give one?

Well, $c^f/c^g=c^{f-g}$; if you want this to tend to $1$ you should require $f-g$ to tend to zero. This really need not hold, of course; $f/g\to 1$ is different to $f-g\to1$, e.g. consider $x\mapsto x+1$ and $x\mapsto x$. Already, that example shows you $c^f\sim c^g$ is false in general, the ratio $c^f/c^g$ being constantly equal to $c$, so long as $c\neq1$.
Getting a counterexample for $c^f=\Theta(c^g)$ is similar; we just need a more dramatic failure. Consider instead $f(x)=x^2+x,g(x)=x^2$. Now $c^f/c^g=c^x\to\infty$ if $c>1$, e.g. for $c=3$, and $c^f=\Theta(c^g)$ is very false.
Intuitively, the point is that exponentiation by $c$ is going to seriously amplify any differences between $f$ and $g$, in an uncontrollable way.
